# Singlelogout not working in okta spring app

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, okta-api

I am trying to test springboot-saml singlelogout with Okta . I am facing a error when I hit /saml/logout/ . The Spring log says "Received LogoutResponse has invalid status code " . The Okta app log says "Unable to validate SAML Logout Request: [a1f8d8g1ged7c86d277iebbihcfecj] - Issuer [demosaml] does not match the Issuer configured for the application."

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Our developer website has further documentation on the Spring App http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml

In order for the SLO to work, you need to ensure the following:
- That you are using POST binding
- That you have generated a certificate
- That your logout request includes a signature